# Can't find opencv headers in ndk .cpp file

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I am build three libs:

```
libopencv_imgcodecs.a
libopencv_core.a
libopencv_imgproc.a
```

This is my **CMAkeFIle.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

#opencv sources
include_directories( /Users/aliaksandrmirashnichenka/Desktop/opencv )

add_library(

native-opencv-wrapper

SHARED

/Users/aliaksandrmirashnichenka/Desktop/Progects/MyProjects/checkbook/app/src/main/cpp/OpenCVWrapper.cpp

)

target_link_libraries(native-opencv-wrapper

                      PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                      /Users/aliaksandrmirashnichenka/Desktop/Progects/MyProjects/checkbook/app/src/main/cpp/include/armeabi/libopencv_imgcodecs.a
                      /Users/aliaksandrmirashnichenka/Desktop/Progects/MyProjects/checkbook/app/src/main/cpp/include/armeabi/libopencv_core.a
                      /Users/aliaksandrmirashnichenka/Desktop/Progects/MyProjects/checkbook/app/src/main/cpp/include/armeabi/libopencv_imgproc.a
)
```

This is my **OpenCVWrapper.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>

#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs_c.h>
```

**I have error "Cannot find 'opencv2'"**

Whats can be wrong? Thanks for answers

Comment: `I have error "Cannot find 'opencv2'"` - **Complete** error message, please. Currently it is unclear, whether you get error when compile, link or run.

Comment: I have this problem in android studio when i'm trying add this is header

Comment: Check that directory you pass to `include_directories` actually contains given header.

Comment: @Tsyvarev

Yes. I'm add path to header and all began working

Like that:

/Users/aliaksandrmirashnichenka/Desktop/opencv/modules/core/include